# Angular.js: Seconds to HH:mm:ss filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

I have a number of seconds count, for example, 713 seconds. How can I implement an Angular.js filter that converts this 713 seconds to HH:mm:ss format? In this case, it should be 00:11:53

```html
<div>
  {{ 713 | secondsToHHMMSS }} <!-- Should output 00:11:53 -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

manzapanza's answer only works if the seconds are less than 86400 (1 day). The date object needs to be completely zero. Also, it would be better to return the actual date object so that angularjs does not have to make it again.

```
app.filter('secondsToDateTime', function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        var d = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
        d.setSeconds(seconds);
        return d;
    };
});
```

and

```
<b>{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</b>
```

---

**Edit:** If you want hours to go above 24 without wrapping to days it is better to not use Date:

```
app.filter('secondsToTime', function() {

    function padTime(t) {
        return t < 10 ? "0"+t : t;
    }

    return function(_seconds) {
        if (typeof _seconds !== "number" || _seconds < 0)
            return "00:00:00";

        var hours = Math.floor(_seconds / 3600),
            minutes = Math.floor((_seconds % 3600) / 60),
            seconds = Math.floor(_seconds % 60);

        return padTime(hours) + ":" + padTime(minutes) + ":" + padTime(seconds);
    };
});
```

and

```
<b>{{seconds | secondsToTime}}</b>
```

Comment: what is "app" here ? in `app.filter`, where should we put the filter exactly ?

Comment: @DanyY app is your module: var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

Answer (score 77):

Try something like this:

```
app.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

html:

```
<b>{{seconds | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</b>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z18j7o2q/2/)

Comment: 2 years later -> still elegant

Comment: Time doesn't matter on the internet. This answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```js
app.filter('secondsToHHmmss', function($filter) {
    return function(seconds) {
        return $filter('date')(new Date(0, 0, 0).setSeconds(seconds), 'HH:mm:ss');
    };
})
```

html:

```html
<b>{{seconds | secondsToHHmmss}}</b>
```

Comment: I needed to drop the `[ ]` to make this work and divide seconds by 1000 as I was dealing with milliseconds

Comment: Thanks. Just revised.

Answer (score 5):

```
app.filter('formatTimer', function () {
return function (input) {
    function z(n) { return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n; }
    var seconds = input % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(input % 3600 / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(input / 3600);
    return (z(hours) + ':' + z(minutes) + ':' + z(seconds));
};
```

will output: 02:04:14

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not necessary the custom filter

```
<b>{{hours}}{{seconds | date:':mm:ss'}}</b>

function Scoper($scope) {
    $scope.seconds = '79000';
    $scope.hours = parseInt($scope.seconds / 3600);
}
```

Comment: The custom filter might not necessary be but the second you need this logic on a different page, the minimal extra time investment to have a filter or directive would then pay off. And you could stash this on the root scope, but that's another codesmell you should ignore.

Answer (score 0):

by @manzapanza solution for days:

```
  $scope.duration_for = function(seconds){
    if(!seconds) return
    var duration = new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds)

    var mask = 'HH:mm'
    if(seconds >= 86400){
      mask = 'd days,' + mask
    }

    return $filter('date')(duration, mask);
  }
```

in view:

```
{{duration_for(100500)}}
```