# AngularJS: Executing a function after timeout ends

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this angularJS app which has a countdown timer. I want to execute a function after it becomes zero. It currently goes into negative after it reaches 0. How to achieve this?

Angular Code:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout' ,function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $timeout) {
  $scope.counter = 5000;
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){
        $scope.counter--;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
  }
}]);


testControllers.filter('formatTimer', function() {
  return function(input)
    {
        function z(n) {return (n<10? '0' : '') + n;}
        var seconds = input % 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(input / 60);
        var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        return (z(hours) +':'+z(minutes)+':'+z(seconds));
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div><p>{{counter|formatTimer}}</p></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply stop calling it when the counter is 0:

```
$scope.onTimeout = function(){
  if (--$scope.counter > 0) {
    $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
  } else {
    // Call your function now that counter is 0
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function at least once for it to keep calling itself:https://jsfiddle.net/L05oepmv/ (which you did in your code above, your jsfiddle is different)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you are doing, you probably don't need to put your timeout method on the scope. Also, look at $interval instead. It's better suited for calling something continuously.

```
function decreaseCounter() {
  if(--$scope.counter <= 0) {
    $interval.cancel(intervalPromise);
    yourOtherFunction();  
  }
}

var intervalPromise = $interval(decreaseCounter, 1000);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 0):

If you need a precise countdown (specially if the time span is large) you need to calculate the time spent using Date time function. Simply incrementing a counter each 1000 milliseconds 5000 times, doesen't guarantee that at the end, the real time spent will be exactly 5000 seconds!

You could try something like this:

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
  var intervalId;

  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.initialCountdown = 10;
  $scope.countdown = $scope.initialCountdown;

  $scope.timer = function(){
    var startTime = new Date();
    intervalId = $interval(function(){
        var actualTime = new Date();
        $scope.counter = Math.floor((actualTime - startTime) / 1000);
        $scope.countdown = $scope.initialCountdown - $scope.counter;
    }, 1000);
  };

  $scope.$watch('countdown', function(countdown){
    if (countdown === 0){
        $scope.stop();
    }
  });

  $scope.start = function(){
    $scope.timer();
  };

  $scope.stop = function(){
    $interval.cancel(intervalId);
  };

}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div>Counter: {{counter}}</div>
  <div>Countdown in seconds: {{countdown}}</div>  
  <div>Countdown date time: {{countdown | secondsToDateTime | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</div>  
  <button ng-click="start()">start</button>
  <button ng-click="stop()">stop</button>      
</div>
```

[Filter secondsToDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28401099/1375596):

```
myApp.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

[CHECK THE DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z18j7o2q/2/)

Enjoy!