# how can i make an angular countdown in minutes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, countdown

Here is my code but I can't find how to make the countdown in minutes, I mean, instead of 3000, 30:00... any help?

```
  <script>
  app.controller("Counter", function($scope,$timeout){
    $scope.counter = 3000;
    $scope.onTimeout = function(){
        $scope.counter--;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
    }
    var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout,1000);
});
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to do the calculations yourself. Has nothing to do with angular, is javascript math and string compiling

Comment: what do you mean? make the countdown in every 30 minutes?

Comment: Yes, that's right, instead of that, i had 3000 seconds, but i solved it with @Muli Yulzary 's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your controller is OK, you only need to:

- change 3000 to 1800 (30 minutes is 1800 seconds).
- add condition before decrementing `counter` to avoid turn around:
  `if ($scope.counter > 0) $scope.counter--;`

Now to display seconds as `'mm:ss'` convert counter to date. You can use filter (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28401099/4989081))

```
app.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
    return function(seconds) {
        return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
    };
}])
```

and display it like that:

```
{{counter | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}
```

**See how it works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd4bf1p5/65) or in snippet below.**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.counter = 1800;
  $scope.onTimeout = function() {
    if ($scope.counter > 0) $scope.counter--;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
  }
  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
}

myApp.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
  return function(seconds) {
    return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
  };
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{counter | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brief example.

view:

```
<div ng-controller="countCtrl">
<span>{{30 - secondsPassed/60}}:{{59 - secondsPassed%60}}</span>
<button ng-click="startTimer()">Click me to start the timer</button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
.controller('countCtrl', function($scope, $interval){
 $scope.secondsPassed = 0;
 var ref;

 $scope.startTimer = function(){
  //Clean interval instance if button clicked multiple times.
  $interval.cancel(ref);
  $scope.secondsPassed = 0;
  ref = $interval(function(){
   $scope.secondsPassed++;
   if($scope.secondsPassed >= 30 * 60){
    //Clean interval instance if we passed the 30 min mark.
    $interval.cancel(ref);
   }
  }, 1000);
 };

 //Clean the interval instance if scope destroyed
 $scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  $interval.cancel(ref);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The above  answers resets the time after 00:00 seconds and counts down from 59:59 again.

> i have changed the answer to stop once reached 00:00

```
app.controller('fiveCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.counter = 3000;
  $scope.onTimeout = function () {
    if ($scope.counter == 0) {
        $scope.counter = 0;
    }
    else{
        $scope.counter--;
        mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
    }       
 }
 var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
});


app.filter('secondsToDateTime', [function() {
       return function(seconds) {
    return new Date(1970, 0, 1).setSeconds(seconds);
   };
}])
```

> the Html would be

```
  <div ng-controller="fiveCtrl">
   <b> Test time Left : {{counter | secondsToDateTime | date:'mm:ss'}}</b> 
     <div ng-show="counter<60 && counter!=0"> Test expires in {{counter}} seconds</div>
     <div ng-show="counter==0"> Test expired : {{counter}} seconds left</div>
  </div>
```